# Tomcat Manager app not showing active sessions when configure to store sessions using memcache

Tags: tomcat, memcached, tomcat-manager

I've configured tomcat to use memcache as the session storage. Prior to this I have been able to inspect and count how many active sessions are current using the tomcat /manager webapp.

After configuring tomcat to use memcache, however, I've noticed that I can't see the active sessions anymore and it always gets reported as zero (0).

Is there a configuration either in memcache or tomcat that I'm missing?

Here is how I configured tomcat context.xml

```
<Manager className="de.javakaffee.web.msm.MemcachedBackupSessionManager"
memcachedNodes="n1:localhost:11211,n2:localhost:11212"

sticky="false"
sessionBackupAsync="false"
requestUriIgnorePattern=".*\.(ico|png|gif|jpg|css|js)$"
/>
```